# Change the id values - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

In my project in asp.net I have 2 different tables. Each of them has ID variable. one called `publicParkingID` and the other `parkingLotID`

My problem is that when I was updating the tables the numbering of the **two tables** starts at 1.

[image]

I want to update / change the id's VALUES of the second table so they start with 100 and go on.

I am realy new with asp.net..

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFvq5.png)

[image]

Comment: You might be stuck with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why you need it starts with 100 at the first place?

Comment: I just need them to be different numbers.

Comment: Why do you need them to be different numbers? They represent different information. Having an overlap shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the identity seed for the table parkingLotID to 100: you can use following code snippet

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT parkingLotID ON
DBCC checkident ('parkingLotID', reseed, 100)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT parkingLotID OFF
```

**Second Approach**

To alter a current table:

```
ALTER TABLE parkingLotID ALTER COLUMN Id IDENTITY (100, 1);
```

Comment: go to your database and  run the query

Comment: No I'm really sorry but I need more information how to do it... ):

Comment: appreciate it a lot

Comment: Run the query from Management studio or visual studio

Comment: This will solve this out - I want to update / change the id's VALUES of the second table so they start with 100 and go on. ?

Comment: I mean that I want to change all the id's in the table (+100)

Comment: Have you run the query

Comment: Where to put it? in the model / controller / view / configuration ?

Comment: It's database query. need to run on database

Comment: where is it? SORRY AND THANK YOU! I've put update picture above

Comment: At SQL Server Object Explorer find your DB then right click on it > select New Query > type the cmd @santoshsingh provided and press execute button at the upper left.

Comment: The name of the table is parkingLot so I tried :                                         
SET IDENTITY_INSERT parkingLot ON
DBCC checkident ('parkingLot', reseed, 100)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT parkingLot OFF                                                           and I also try this - ALTER TABLE parkingLot ALTER COLUMN Id int (100, 1);

Comment: can you share your screen over teamviewer

Comment: Ive upload a pic up at the first question

Comment: difficult to tell anything by seeing the image

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162103/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-tamir-hazan).